# Dinic's algorithm for multiple sink, single source maxflow problem

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, deep-copy

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that would find two sinks such that the total flow from a given source is largest. I'm using Dinic's algorithm and largerly basing my implementation on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dinics-algorithm-maximum-flow/) version with appropriate driver function:

```
def maxflow( G,s ):
    g = Graph( G )
    maximum=0
    for i in range( g.V ):
        g.addEdge( ( i, g.V-1, float('inf') ) )
        g2 = copy.deepcopy( g )
        for j in range(g2.V):
            if j == i or j == s or i==s:
                continue
            g2.addEdge( ( j, g.V-1, float('inf') ) )
            maximum = max( g2.DinicMaxflow( s, g.V-1 ), maximum )
            g2 = copy.deepcopy( g )
        g.removeVirtualSink(i)
    return maximum
```

As far as I know there really isn't a better way of doing this other than checking every possible pair of vertices. The problem I have is that due to the algorithm leaving a residual matrix I need a way to store a "default" state of the graph so that I can return to it after every `DinicMaxflow()` call, however `deepcopy()` is terribly slow.
Is there a way to either copy the data faster or preferably make it so that I don't have to copy the data after every function call?

Comment: Multiple vs single source or sink make no difference to dinic's (or any maxflow) implementation. Simply modify your graph and turn each "sink" into a normal node connecting to a true sink with infinite capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same problem, I came up with a solution: where u make an extra node: connected it to all the start node with infinite flow range and consider it as starting node.
In the sink, same case, connect to an extra node, connect it to all previous sink nodes with inf range and consider this new node as an final sink.
dinic's algorithm is already an complex one, while multiple start and sink add more complexity. so this trick might help. I tested the implementation and always worked.
Have a nice day.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please make your answer clearer and add examples or code to it